# How do we get around the fact that 'extera' appears rarely as masculine

Tags: classical-latin

In the OLD it says that 'exter' is rare as a nom sing masc adjective but in the LASLA database it does not appear at all as a masc positive adjective in any case.  As a superlative the masculine 'extremus' appears 16 times.  So if you want to modify a masculine noun with 'exter' do you just use a different adjective or do you use the feminine or neuter form of the adjective?

Comment: What is "the LASLA database" and what bearing does it have whether a word form appears in it? *Exter* is rare and unclassical, but it is attested.

Comment: https://classicalstudies.org/scs-blog/patrick-j-burns/review-opera-latina

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> So if you want to modify a masculine noun with 'exter' do you just use
> a different adjective or do you use the feminine or neuter form of the
> adjective?

My short answer would be to use the forms *externus* or *exterior* to avoid the potential problem, since no one can be certain what forms were acceptable in what contexts at any given period.  Below is my longer answer.

Implicit in your question is the issue of what standard we should use in writing Latin.  For the sake of argument, let's say you are trying to write Latin that we think Cicero, Julius Caesar, or another "Classical Latin" author would consider morphologically correct and/or good style.

[Lewis & Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic%20letter%3DE%3Aentry%20group%3D47%3Aentry%3Dexter) says of ***exter(us)***:

> exter or extĕrus (**both forms** **only post-class. and very rare**), tĕra,
> tĕrum, adj. comp. form, from ex, I.on the outside, outward, of another
> country, family, etc., foreign, strange (syn.: extraneus; alienus,
> peregrinus, adventicius). I. Pos. (in Cic. and Caes. used in the
> plur.): “quod exter heres praestare cogeretur,” strange, Dig. 31, 1,
> 69: “emancipatus vero aut exterus non aliter possunt hereditatem
> quaerere quam si, etc.,” ib. 29, 2, 84

From this entry, we learn that Lewis & Short agree that the masculine singular nominative forms *exter/exterus* do not appear in classical Latin literature, but they are found "rarely"  and at least in the sixth century *[Digest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_(Roman_law))*.  The relative lack of citations raises the question: Is the rarity or lack of forms a systemic issue, or just an artifact of the fact chance has not allowed these forms to appear in the literature that happened to survive?  Also, does sixth century usage imply that classical usage would have been fine, even if not attested?

We can begin to resolve this question be looking at other words of a similar structure and parallel meaning.

For ***poster(us)***, we find in [Lewis & Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=posterus&la=la#lexicon):

> postĕrus or poster (**not in use in I.nom. sing. masc.**), a, um,
> adj.—Comp: posterior, us.—Sup.: postremus or postumus, a, um [post],
> coming after, following, next, ensuing, future.

For **super(us)**, we find in [Lewis & Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=superus&la=la#lexicon):

> sŭpĕrus , a, um (**ante-class. collat. form** of the I.nom. sing. sŭpĕr **in
> two passages**: “super inferque vicinus,” Cato, R. R. 149, 1: “totus
> super ignis,” Lucr. 1, 649; gen. plur. in signif. I. B. 1. infra,
> superūm, Verg. A. 1, 4; Ov. M. 1, 251 et saep.), adj. super.

For ***infer(us)*** in the [same source](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=inferus&la=la#lexicon):

> infĕrus , a, um (**ante-class. collat. form of the I.nom. sing. infer**:
> “ubi super inferque vicinus permittet,” Cato, R. R. 149), adj. cf.
> Sanscr. adh-aras, adh-amas, the lower, lowest; and Lat. infra, that is
> below, underneath, lower; opp. superus.

We find no adjective form corresponding to ***inter(us)** or ***anter(us)**, but do find ***dexter*** and ***sinister*** in all forms.

From these data, one can conclude that there was hesitancy around the masculine singular nominative form of all the adjectives related to basic adverbs/prepositions of position that had ready comparatives in *-(t)erior*.  What may have caused this hesitancy is hard to say, but several factors immediately present themselves.

First, although all the above words appear to have a similar structure and similar derivational possibilities, the roots/stems themselves do not have the same structure and are not all the same part of speech.  Some have a form ending in "er(us)," others a form ending in "ter(us)."  Of those not ending in a "t" in their basic form, some add one to make "ter(us)"; while others do not.

In some of these roots, forms ending in "-er" conflict with the form of the base adverb or preposition.  This conflict and the varying semantics is probably why we have no adjective of the form *inter*, but then again Cato seems to have had no problem with using *super* and *infer* as adjectives, which at least had the same semantics as the corresponding prepositions.

Even more important than the the structure of these words is the fact the comparative forms of these words are very often used with almost the same meanings as the positive forms.  There is little need for an *exter(us)* if *exterior* carries just about the same meaning, especially if there is hesitancy around which form is appropriate.  It is telling that all the comparative forms have survived into English, but almost none of the positive forms.  It is also telling that we find *exter(us)* only in a legal document, where a feeling of precision, formality, and archaism would have been desired stylistic traits.

In addition, there are ready synonyms of many of these words formed from the same roots by adding *-(t)ernus*, such as *externus*, giving yet another classical option for avoiding a dubious form.  Such stacking of suffixes happened with many Latin words over time so that we eventually ended up structurally with *ex > exter > externus > externalis*.

Comment: Thank you once again, Vegawatcher, your answers are quite simply amazing!